# Deserialize XML from one class into a new one without old class in project

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a project with a class that gets XML serialized, and this class has a property of another class type. I want to delete this class, and move the other class (the property class) to a new project and at the same time, change the structure of the property class and its children (add new properties, remove old ones, renames, etc). I know if I was just moving a class I could use the `XmlType` attribute on my class to get existing objects to deserialize into the new class / project / assembly, but this workflow seems more complex than that. Is it possible?

Some example code below.

The old class that I want to delete:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(BaseStyle))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(MyStyle))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(YourStyle))]
public class Node
{
   public BaseStyle Style {get;set;}
   // More stuff, most of it irrelevant
}
```

The `BaseStyle` class and its children are defined as

```
public class BaseStyle
{
   public string Description = string.Empty;
}

public class MyStyle : BaseStyle
{
   public double Factor1 = 1.0;
   public double Factor2 = 2.0;
}

public class YourStyle : BaseStyle
{
   public double Constant = 10.0;
   public DefaultValuesClass DefaultValues = null;
}
```

So all of that gets serialized into XML fine, and the resulting XML looks something like

```
<Node>
   <Style p2:type="YourStyle" xmlns:p2="blah">
      <Constant>5.0</Constant>
      <DefaultValues>
       // XML for the DefaultValuesClass class here
      </DefaultValues>
   </Style>
</Node>
```

Now, I've removed the `Node` class entirely (although there is an analog to it in the new assembly); moved the `Style` classes to another assembly; renamed them to `BaseModel`, `MyModel`, and `YourModel`; changed `BaseModel` and its `Description` property to be abstract; and changed `YourModel` so it now looks like:

```
public sealed class YourModel : BaseModel
{
   public double Constant {get; set;}
   public bool UseDefaults {get; set;}
   public NewDefaultValuesClass Defaults {get; set;}
   public override Description => "This is your model";
}
```

I want to map the `<Constant>` XML tag to `YourModel.Constant`, the `<DefaultValues>` XML tag to `YourModel.UseDefaults` and `YourModel.Defaults`, and provide a predefined prescription based on the fact that it is of type `YourStyle` (or just use the default provided in `YourModel`).

If I kept `Node` around (and maybe `BaseStyle` and its children?), I could write some custom deserialization code, or write a conversion utility to run from a context menu or during loading, but I'd rather not keep `Node`. I'd also rather not rename any of the XML elements to be "Node" as that would get confusing down the road. Since I know the structure of the existing XML, is there a way I can use it to populate new `MyModel` and `YourModel` objects, without having the class definition of `Node`?

I hope this all made sense, please leave a comment if I need to clarify.

Comment: I guess with the amount of changes you're making to the data model it might perhaps be a better idea to load the file in an XDocument and use Linq2XML to project the contained data according to what you want to have now. Depending on how complex the NewDefaultValues class structure is this could be solved in just a couple of lines of LINQ.